# jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 navigate then comes back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a strange problem with my jQuery mobile application.
I used a single html file with multiple pages.

My problem is in the navigation, here is what append :

PageA ==(navigate)==> PageB ==> PageC => Click Home button (from dialog) -> Back to PageA.

Everything is fine, my page shows events are as I want.

I can do these actions 2-3 times and the 4th time here is the problem :

- Page A
- Page B
- Page C
- Open Dialog, Click Home Button
- PageA fire show event
- **PageC fire show event too**
- PageC is visible even if in the navBar I have PageA

This is my OnClick :

```
$("#VisitHomeButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.mobile.navigate('#patientListPage');
    return;
});
```

I noticed, by using breakpoints, that the PageC event fires just after PageA event but not wait the end of my PageA method.

I am stuck on this since 3 days. If someone have any idea how to find the source of this problem it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#patientListPage");`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but I still have the same behaviour. I came back on my PageC (VisitPage)

Comment: when you navigate to pages, you use _anchors_ or `change page` function?

Comment: Mostly with `change page` but I have some anchors.
The problem I think is not in how I change my pages, I can't understand why it's showing an other page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a stupid error.

On my PageB :

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#PageB", function() {
    $("#checkIDButton").click(function(event) {
        $.mobile.navigate("#VisitPage");
    });
});
```

just add :

```
$("#checkIDButton").off();
```

Fixed everything.

Comment: Bind click event on `pagecreate` it'll fire once only to avoid multiple click events attached to the same anchor.

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page_ID", function () { click events };` you're welcome :)